# Apache config virtual hosts with client certification

Tags: apache-2.2

From the same host i will serve two sub domains with SSL, but one of them also needs client authentification.

```
NameVirtulaHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName mail.example.com

        SSLEngine on

        SSLCACertificateFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
        SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName erp.example.com

        SSLEngine on
        SSLVerifyClient require

        SSLCACertificateFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
        SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key

</VirtualHost>
```

With the above config SSL is activated but no client certificate needed. If i change the 
order (first erp.example.com) then both domains need client certificate.

(Apache/2.2.9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply first read this..

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslverifyclient

it explains how to use SSLVerifyRequire

*In per-directory context it forces a SSL renegotation with the reconfigured client verification level after the HTTP request was read but before the HTTP response is sent.*

Any other questions please ask..

Hope this helps :D

Comment: You got me in the right direction. I didn't see this applicable because the erp.example.com is a proxy, but seems to work similiar. Thank you.